# ¿Como llenar un DataGrid con registros obtenidos de una base de datos?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf

Quiero llenar un DataGrid que tiene columnas predefinas y los datos se obtienen de una base de datos. Anteriormente utilizaba el siguiente codigo para llenar el **DataGrid** realizado con **C#** en **Visual Studio 2017** en una ventana **(WPF)**

```
public void llenarDataGrid()
{
    String consulta = "select idUsuario,Nombre,ApellidoP,ApellidoM,Sexo,Telefono,Edad,Puesto from usuarios;";
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(consulta,new BaseDeDatos().obtenerConexion());
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
    dataGridUsuarios.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
}
```

El **DataGrid** quedo de la siguiente manera despues de ingresar las columnas[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pongo el **idUsuario** en la consulta por que me gustaria que al momento de seleccionar algun registro obtener el **idUsuario** en lugar de obtener el indice de la fila

Comment: por lo que muestras, la variable dataAdapter la declaras y la instancias , pero en nigun momento la utilizas dentro del metodo, es probable que ahi radique el problema

Comment: Disculpa, me salte una linea pero ese no es el problema.. a si funciona pero los datos me los pone despues las columnas que yo predefini y crea sus propias columas de la consulta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentar hacer los siguiente, obtener las tablas dentro de tu `dataset`

```
DataTableCollection collection = ds.Tables;
```

Posterior a eso obtienes la `DataTable` que contiene los datos:

```
DataTable table = collection[0];
```

hasta ahi tienes una `DataTable` que haremos uso posteriormente.

**El ejemplo** que pondre no seran con todos tus datos pero se que se entendera para que puedas reproducirlo.

Tu `datagrid` debe de ser editado para poder ingresar datos desde el codigo, ya que añadiste columnas por defecto debes agregar un **binding** a todas tus columnas:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridUsuarios" CanUserAddRows="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="64,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="210" Width="364">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=nombre}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="nombre" HeaderStringFormat="Nombre" Width="100"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=apellido}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="apellido" HeaderStringFormat="Apellido" Width="100"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=sexo}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="sexo" HeaderStringFormat="Sexo" Width="80"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=edad}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="edad" HeaderStringFormat="Edad" Width="70"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Las partes como `Binding="{Binding Path=nombre}"` son las importantes aqui ya que gracias a estas se importaran los datos.

Posterior a ese deberás crear una clase para añadir tus filas con todos los datos que seas mostrar, en mi ejemplo solo trabajare con cuatro: **nombre, apellido, sexo, edad.**

Entonces:

```
 public class Modelo
 {
     public string nombre { get; set; }
     public string apellido { get; set; }
     public string sexo { get; set; }
     public string edad { get; set; }
 }
```

Entonces imaginemos que mi `datatable` **table**, anteriormente mencionado tiene esos datos, lo que ahora debemos hacer es recorrer ese `datatable` para añadir esos contenidos a nuestro datagrid.

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    var data = new Modelo { nombre = row["Nombre"].ToString(), apellido = row["Apellidos"].ToString(), sexo = row["Sexo"].ToString(), edad = row["Edad"].ToString() };
    dataGridUsuarios.Items.Add(data);
}
```

donde los `row["Nombre"]` son valores de tu consulta, tu tendras unos de esta forma:

```
row["idUsuario"]
row["Nombre"]
row["ApellidoP"]
row["ApellidoM"]// y asi con todos tus datos.
```

Posterior a eso tendria que darte un resultado similar a este.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ademas ten en cuenta que los **Path=nombre** de tu archivo xaml deben tener el mismo formato de tu modelo.

Ademas, sobre el **id** que mecionas que deseas poner lo puedes hacer como los hiciste con las otras columnas pero como este no deberia de poder verse, puedes definirlo con `Visibility="Hidden"`. **Ej:**

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=id}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="id" HeaderStringFormat="id" Visibility="Hidden"/>
```

Comment: Creo que algo hice mal.. anteriormente me daba error por que entre tanta prueba elimine `dataAdapter.Fill(ds);` ahora no me marca error pero tampoco me muestra los registros.. solo para confirmar en el **Path=nombre** te refieres a que debe llevar el mismo nombre que el modelo de base de datos ?

Comment: Quiero pensar que en parte esta bien por que aparece como si tubiera 2 registros la tabla que son los que realidad tiene pero estan en blanco....cree la clase y todo modifique un par de cosas adapte todo segun lo que nesecito pero siguiendo tus instrucciones pero no me muestra nada

Comment: E solucionado, al parecer entendi mal los nombre de las variables en la clase **Modelo**  deben tener el mismo nombre que los que se declaran en el **Binding** o por lo menos a si lo solucione.

Comment: que bueno que te resulto, perdon por no responder antes aqui donde vivo era hora de dormir...

Answer (score 1):

ya he realizado una prueba en WPF con el datagrid, si ya tienes tu modelo de datos, de los cuales solamente deseas mostrar solo algunos en tu datagrid puedes realizar lo siguiente y utilizar un tipo anonimo con los datos que requieres mostrar y en base a ellos configurar las columnas de tu datagrid como los encabezados y ocultar por decir la columna del ID para que lo obtengas cuando requieras hacer algo con el elemento seleccionado.

Yo tengo este modelo:

```
public class Producto
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductoID { get; set; }    

    [Required, MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Se han excedido el numero de caracteres {0}"), MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Nombre de producto demasiado corto")]
    public string NombreProducto { get; set; }

    public decimal PrecioVenta { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime FechaCreado { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime FechaModificado { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Y quiero en mi datagrid el ID, NombreProducto y PrecioVenta, realizo lo siguiente:

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var db = new LaundryDB())
        {
            //Obtengo todos mis productos de mi BD 
            var productos = from p in db.Productos.ToList()
                            select new { p.ProductoID, p.NombreProducto, p.PrecioVenta}; //selecciono con tipo anonimo solo los campos que me interesan

            //La lista de productos queda con 3 campos que me interesa
            //ProductoID - Index(0) 
            //NombreProducto Index(1)
            //PrecioVenta - Index(2) 

            //Asigno mi lista de productos como origen de datos del datagrid
            dgvProductos.ItemsSource = productos;

            //Oculto el campo ProductoID, que no deseo mostrar  
            dgvProductos.Columns[0].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; //Index 0 - ProductoID

            //Modifico cabeceras de columnas
            dgvProductos.Columns[1].Header = "Nombre del producto o servicio"; //Index 1 - NombreProducto
            dgvProductos.Columns[2].Header = "Precio de venta"; //Index 2 - PrecioVenta
        }
    }
```

Y este es el resultado, desconozco porque sale una columna adicional en blanco, pero ya que manejas WPF has de saber que sucede o alguien mas podría ayudar con esa parte

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que tal nuevamente, con este código lograrás obtener el ID de tu usuario que sea seleccionado de tu datagrid, espero te sea de utilidad, hazlo en el evento SelectionChanged de tu DG, en mi ejemplo lo que hago es poner el ID del producto seleccionado en un textbox, que se encuentra arriba de mi datagrid, saludos.

```
    private void dgvProductos_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {            
        var ID = (dgvProductos.SelectedItem as Producto).ProductoID;
        txtID.Text = ID.ToString();
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: E utilizado el ejemplo que he seleccionado que me ayudo pero tengo problemas para obtener el id que lo puse como oculto, ya que es diferente a lo que estoy acostumbrado no puedo obtener el valor.

Comment: Editaré mi respuesta, en la parte final te pongo como logre obtener el ProductoID de mi ejemplo, que creo que la funcionalidad que buscas, buen dia

Answer (score 0):

Te pone las columnas después de las columnas que tú predefiniste porque no coinciden los nombres de dichas columnas.

Para solucionarlo solo modifica tu consulta para que coincida el título de cada columna del Datagridview:

```
String consulta = "select idUsuario,Nombre,ApellidoP AS 'Apellido Paterno',ApellidoM AS 'Apellido materno',Sexo,Telefono,Edad,Puesto from usuarios;"
```

Asumo que la columna idUsuario la tienes oculta en tu Datagridview, de lo contrario tendrías que quitarla de la consulta. Un Saludo.

Comment: Ya lo hice y sigue haciendo lo mismo copie cada titulo de las columnas para que coincidan y sigue todo igual.. solo por si acaso no uso DataGridView ya que en las herrmaientas de controles de una ventana **(WPF)** no me aparece el **DataGridView** solo el **DataGrid** y el **idUsuario** lo quiero para que cuando seleccione algun registro me de el **idUsuario** del registro y no del indice de la fila.

Comment: Tienes razón, no me percaté de esa parte (WPF) y que es un DataGrid, pero una duda... ¿La columna idUsuario si la tienes oculta en el DataGrid?

Comment: No simplemente no cree esa columa solo cree o mejor dicho predifini las que estan en la imagen.. pero por lo que ya comente si me interesa tomar en cuenta aun que no se la muestre al usuario.

Comment: Ok, pienso que por eso es. Yo he trabajado con el DataGridView y cuando alguna columna no coincide ya sea en nombre o en el orden me hace exactamente lo mismo. Prueba a predefinir la columna idUsuario al principio en el DataGrid y ocúltala si deseas, pero si tiene que estar incluída.

Comment: Ya hice esa prueba lo quite de la consulta y puse los mismos nombre en la consulta similar al de las columnas para que no se acople a lo que me comentaste en tu respuesta..  pero sigue realizando lo mismo..
a qui la consulta que puse
select Nombre,ApellidoP  as 'Apellido Paterno',ApellidoM as 'Apellido materno',Sexo,Telefono,Edad,Puesto from usuarios;

Answer (score 0):

Hola que tal a mi me estaba pasando exactamente lo mismo con un DataGridView, en el cual agregué las columnas que deseo mostrar en mi aplicacion y las que deseo ocultar como el ID para usarlo como tú piensas hacerlo, eso lo solucioné como te comentaron arriba, tiene que coincidir el nombre de la columna de mi DGV con el que tienes en tu BD, y además en la propiedad Datos, en DataPropertyName poner el mismo nombre del dato que estás trayendo para que de esa forma no te duplique la columna y te aparezca una sola vez y con los datos obtenidos de tu consulta, de esa forma fue mi solución y ojalá sea el mismo funcionamiento en WPF con el DataGrid, saludos y te dejo una captura

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Déjame verificar si en WPF es el mismo funcionamiento, ya que no he desarrollado en él, mas que WinForms, y te paso la información.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno lei todo el post porque siempre ando en windows forms y es bastante complejo tratar de llenar un datagrid, por lo que veo no hay manera simple?

Me pasa exactamente igual tengo una consulta que con un boton llena automaticamente mi datagridview en winforms aqui como lo hago ya que uso un textbox.1

```
    private DataTable llenar_grid()
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        string query = "SELECT TOP(500) [clienteid],medioFROM [col].[dbo].[bog] WHERE medios in (" +TextBox1.Text+ ")";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conexion.conectado());
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 99999;
        new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(dataTable);
        return dataTable;
    }

 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        datagrid.ItemsSource = llenar_grid();
    }
```

Si alguien encuentra este inconveniente tambien se puede de la siguiente manera definir un datatable DS y de alli podes usar como si fuese winforms

DataSet DS = new DataSet();

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        string query = "SELECT TOP(500)  [clienteid],medioFROM [col].[dbo].[bog] WHERE medios in (" +TextBox1.Text+ ")";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conexion.conectado());
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 99999;
        new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(DS);
       

        datagrid.ItemsSource = DS.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    }
```

Comment: pregunta la actualice para ver si es posible que alguien me ayude

Comment: Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, este apartado es especifico para responder, si tienes alguna duda, pregunta o un problema similar debes crear una nueva pregunta, te recomiendo que leas [ask],

Comment: si uso mas el perfil ingles pero te agradezco el comentario